# Windows 10 installation via USB error

Tags: windows, usb, windows-10, installation, bcd

I am trying to install Windows 10 from a USB drive because I don't have a DVD.  I get the error:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \boot\bcd

  Status: 0xc0000225
```

I tested a Windows 8.1 ISO and got the same error, so I tested a Windows 7 ISO and, again, got the same error.  When I booted from a Windows 7 DVD, however, it worked.

My computer can boot Ubuntu from a USB.  My USB drive is USB 3.0 but my computer has no USB 3.0 ports.

my computer is:

custom motherbord: ASUS Vintage-AE1 Barebone
ram: 2gig
AMD 64bit

Comment: I had the same issue, but it was because I have forgotten to override boot from USB in BIOS.

Comment: i setup the bios right

Comment: Sorry, it seems that I have mixed things up. The reason for such problem for me was in corrupted installation USB. I have performed slow formatting of the stick, than copied ISO to it again. After that installation was successful.

Comment: did that to i used wintousb to install a potable on my usb same error

Comment: Try rufus, maybe it will make things better.

Comment: this is funny i have done rufus to. I used rufus to make a usb for my bros computer and it worked but not mine i am going to post my bios and computer make and model

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't have support to be installed from USB 3, be sure your using the appropriate version x86, x64 for your hardware, only Windows 8 and above allow 32 UEFI on 64-not hardware and even then there is still hardware support to be considers

Comment: i had a usb 2 i just got a usb 3 for installing windows 10 i am X64 not X86

Answer (score 0):

Use Command prompt to make a bootable usb drive, make sure you upate the bootloader too. Make sure you image file of Windows 10 isn't corrupted. You can get the steps online as how to make a pendrive bootable via CMD. Its easy.

Also check for your harware inside your cpu if everything is connected properly or not. Sometimes some hardware failures can cause this sort of problem.